# How to joint both the data that remain without NaN in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Now I am quite stuck with this coding. As mentions I am terrible at coding.
Now, the problem with my code is it produce `Nan`. Which I think it is not suitable.
Here are my coding and the problem that remains where I search a suitable coding.

I called a part from my large data:

```
df1 =d1['hlogDs_dB'].str.split('[,:]',expand = True)
df2 =d1['hlogUs_dB'].str.split('[,:]',expand = True)
df1 =df1.astype(float)
df2 =df2.astype(float)
frames = [df1,df2]
df = pd.concat(frames)
df
```

Where I have to  dataframe Ds and Us. They have different numbers.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683
0   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.0    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -12.3   491.0   -12.5   492.0   -12.5   493.0   -12.6   494.0   -12.8
1   5.0 -2.1    6.0 -2.0    7.0 -1.8    8.0 -1.8    9.0 -1.8    ... 490.0   -8.5    491.0   -8.3    492.0   -8.3    493.0   -8.2    494.0   -8.2
2   5.0 -2.1    6.0 -2.0    7.0 -1.8    8.0 -1.8    9.0 -1.8    ... 490.0   -13.3   491.0   -13.6   492.0   -14.0   493.0   -14.2   494.0   -14.6
3   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.0    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -11.5   491.0   -11.5   492.0   -11.7   493.0   -11.8   494.0   -12.0
4   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.1    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -13.5   491.0   -13.6   492.0   -13.8   493.0   -14.0   494.0   -14.5
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
165 109.0   -5.2    110.0   -5.3    111.0   -5.5    112.0   -5.7    113.0   -5.9    ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
166 109.0   -5.5    110.0   -5.6    111.0   -5.8    112.0   -6.1    113.0   -6.3    ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
167 109.0   -6.0    110.0   -6.2    111.0   -6.4    112.0   -6.7    113.0   -7.1    ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
168 109.0   -5.4    110.0   -5.5    111.0   -5.7    112.0   -5.9    113.0   -6.2    ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
169 109.0   -5.9    110.0   -6.1    111.0   -6.4    112.0   -6.6    113.0   -7.0    ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
340 rows × 684 columns
```

If seperately Ds

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683
0   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.0    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -12.3   491.0   -12.5   492.0   -12.5   493.0   -12.6   494.0   -12.8
1   5.0 -2.1    6.0 -2.0    7.0 -1.8    8.0 -1.8    9.0 -1.8    ... 490.0   -8.5    491.0   -8.3    492.0   -8.3    493.0   -8.2    494.0   -8.2
2   5.0 -2.1    6.0 -2.0    7.0 -1.8    8.0 -1.8    9.0 -1.8    ... 490.0   -13.3   491.0   -13.6   492.0   -14.0   493.0   -14.2   494.0   -14.6
3   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.0    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -11.5   491.0   -11.5   492.0   -11.7   493.0   -11.8   494.0   -12.0
4   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.1    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -13.5   491.0   -13.6   492.0   -13.8   493.0   -14.0   494.0   -14.5
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
165 5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.1    9.0 -2.1    ... 490.0   -13.3   491.0   -13.5   492.0   -13.5   493.0   -13.6   494.0   -13.7
166 5.0 -2.8    6.0 -2.7    7.0 -2.5    8.0 -2.5    9.0 -2.3    ... 490.0   -12.8   491.0   -13.0   492.0   -13.0   493.0   -13.1   494.0   -13.3
167 5.0 -2.6    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.2    8.0 -2.2    9.0 -2.2    ... 490.0   -15.7   491.0   -15.5   492.0   -15.0   493.0   -14.7   494.0   -14.3
168 5.0 -3.0    6.0 -3.0    7.0 -2.6    8.0 -2.5    9.0 -2.5    ... 490.0   -19.7   491.0   -20.3   492.0   -21.0   493.0   -21.5   494.0   -21.8
169 5.0 -2.7    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.3    8.0 -2.2    9.0 -2.3    ... 490.0   -16.2   491.0   -16.2   492.0   -16.2   493.0   -16.1   494.0   -16.0
170 rows × 684 columns
```

Us:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285
0   109 -3.4    110 -3.4    111 -3.4    112 -3.5    113 -3.5    ... 343 -4.3    344 -4.3    345 -4.2    346 -4.2    347 -4.2
1   109 -3.5    110 -3.5    111 -3.4    112 -3.4    113 -3.4    ... 343 -4.1    344 -4.2    345 -4.4    346 -4.4    347 -4.2
2   109 -3.7    110 -3.7    111 -3.8    112 -3.8    113 -3.8    ... 343 -4.2    344 -4.3    345 -4.3    346 -4.3    347 -4.3
3   109 -3.5    110 -3.6    111 -3.6    112 -3.6    113 -3.7    ... 343 -4.1    344 -4.1    345 -4.1    346 -4.1    347 -4.1
4   109 -3.7    110 -3.8    111 -3.8    112 -3.8    113 -3.8    ... 343 -4.2    344 -4.2    345 -4.2    346 -4.2    347 -4.3
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
165 109 -5.2    110 -5.3    111 -5.5    112 -5.7    113 -5.9    ... 343 -5.4    344 -5.3    345 -5.2    346 -5.1    347 -5.1
166 109 -5.5    110 -5.6    111 -5.8    112 -6.1    113 -6.3    ... 343 -5.5    344 -5.4    345 -5.3    346 -5.2    347 -5.2
167 109 -6.0    110 -6.2    111 -6.4    112 -6.7    113 -7.1    ... 343 -4.9    344 -4.9    345 -4.9    346 -4.9    347 -4.9
168 109 -5.4    110 -5.5    111 -5.7    112 -5.9    113 -6.2    ... 343 -5.9    344 -5.7    345 -5.7    346 -5.6    347 -5.6
169 109 -5.9    110 -6.1    111 -6.4    112 -6.6    113 -7.0    ... 343 -5.7    344 -5.7    345 -5.7    346 -5.6    347 -5.6
170 rows × 286 columns
```

so now, I may do something to filled when the both combine

```
df= df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=0)
df
```

result:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683
0   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.0    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -12.3   491.0   -12.5   492.0   -12.5   493.0   -12.6   494.0   -12.8
1   5.0 -2.1    6.0 -2.0    7.0 -1.8    8.0 -1.8    9.0 -1.8    ... 490.0   -8.5    491.0   -8.3    492.0   -8.3    493.0   -8.2    494.0   -8.2
2   5.0 -2.1    6.0 -2.0    7.0 -1.8    8.0 -1.8    9.0 -1.8    ... 490.0   -13.3   491.0   -13.6   492.0   -14.0   493.0   -14.2   494.0   -14.6
3   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.0    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -11.5   491.0   -11.5   492.0   -11.7   493.0   -11.8   494.0   -12.0
4   5.0 -2.5    6.0 -2.5    7.0 -2.1    8.0 -2.1    9.0 -2.0    ... 490.0   -13.5   491.0   -13.6   492.0   -13.8   493.0   -14.0   494.0   -14.5
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
165 109.0   -5.2    110.0   -5.3    111.0   -5.5    112.0   -5.7    113.0   -5.9    ... 490.0   -16.2   491.0   -16.2   492.0   -16.2   493.0   -16.1   494.0   -16.0
166 109.0   -5.5    110.0   -5.6    111.0   -5.8    112.0   -6.1    113.0   -6.3    ... 490.0   -16.2   491.0   -16.2   492.0   -16.2   493.0   -16.1   494.0   -16.0
167 109.0   -6.0    110.0   -6.2    111.0   -6.4    112.0   -6.7    113.0   -7.1    ... 490.0   -16.2   491.0   -16.2   492.0   -16.2   493.0   -16.1   494.0   -16.0
168 109.0   -5.4    110.0   -5.5    111.0   -5.7    112.0   -5.9    113.0   -6.2    ... 490.0   -16.2   491.0   -16.2   492.0   -16.2   493.0   -16.1   494.0   -16.0
169 109.0   -5.9    110.0   -6.1    111.0   -6.4    112.0   -6.6    113.0   -7.0    ... 490.0   -16.2   491.0   -16.2   492.0   -16.2   493.0   -16.1   494.0   -16.0
340 rows × 684 columns
```

I understand a little. Which I am wrong in understanding it. Can anyone suggest for me learning pandas that suitable for me analysis and make a programmable easily. I am quite down a bit with my limitations knowledge in pandas.

My flow is like this:

1. My code is to extract a columns that has many separator.
2. After extract I split the data into columns that's why it contains and `int` number and `float` number.
3. After that I want to combine the both Us and Ds data and sort number of `int` only that follow with the `float`.
4. Then I use the new `dataframe` to equations that I will do.
5. After that I want to plot the data.

So basically that  is my process. I don't know what to search on google engine. Thank you.

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you use a simpler example - with probably 1 or 2  input columns only for example and the expected output? Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So what is the question? please be precise. What output did you get, what output do you expect?

Comment: @Karina  I apologize for my delay of your comment. I will post another set of question. I will do it after I done a good research for a good question. I really appreciate your helping hand.

Comment: @Mortz. Thank you for giving me a link, I quite stumble in how to ask the question. Appreciate much for giving me some tips.